# Why would Ganache behave differently depending on geth, web3j, web3js and web3.py?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, web3j, web3.py, ganache

I have a smart contract token deployed in a Ganache instance.  My dapp written with React and web3.js shows the same 10 accounts for `eth.accounts` as running the same command in the geth console.

If I create my token object with the abi and contract address in geth, I get a different balance for `accounts[0]` than the balance I get with my dapp.  Both create the token object with the same blockchain address.  Both show that `eth.accounts[0]` is the same address!

I also have an Android app using web3j.  It uses the same contract address and it displays the same values that the React dapp shows.

However, I also have an app in web3.py and it shows the same values that are shown in geth!

Can someone please explain to me how the same token object could display different outputs on `.balanceOf("the_same_address")` if it's in the same blockchain?  The only difference is if I'm using geth, web3j, web3.js or web3.py

EDIT: added picture ob browser with console (dapp) and terminal console (geth)
[image]

It gives me different balances for all accounts.  It feels as if I was connecting to 2 different blockchains.  However, they have the same 10 default accounts and my contracts deployed in the same addresses.

Comment: When you say the balances are "different", do you mean that one is 0?

Comment: No. Balances are completely different numbers.  I also get different results when checking mappings in a contract.  Web3.js will return a different mapping than geth console.

Comment: Can you show the balances as integers before shifting the decimals? The difference seems too large for this, but _maybe_ it's some kind of rounding error. Also, if there's any chance you're connected to two different chains, the best way to confirm you're on the same one is by comparing the latest block hash with: `web3.eth.getBlock('latest').hash`.

Comment: Thanks @carver I was really hoping this would show two different hashes. Unfortunately, it showed the same hash in geth and dapp even though they show different balances.  
We created a new instance and it shows the same balances in all apps.  I still haven't destroyed this instance with hopes of understanding what went wrong.

Comment: A broken token *could* give a different balance depending on who was calling. (and the different web3's might have different default senders) Can you add the solidity to verify no funny business in that function?

Comment: I would also like to get to the bottom of it! All of these web3 interfaces are ultimately connecting over json-rpc, so let's repeat the same call over json-rpc: `curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"to": "<contract_addr>", "data":"0x70a082310000000000000000000000000<non-0x-prefixed-address-to-check-balance-of-here>"}],"id":1}' 127.0.0.1:8545`

Answer (score 0):

Are the results showing in 'eth' values and not in 'wei's? Can you show us the different results you see in geth/ web3j/ js/ py ?

Comment: It's in wei's.  I can convert from wei and its not a rounding problem.  I've added an image to the question.

Comment: In your console, you're typing coin.balanceOf(). Is 'coin' your contract? Are you calling the same 'coin' contract through web3js (UI where it displays 599999400) ? I guess the balance that you're getting in UI is the actual account balance from your blockchain network and coin.balanceOf is the balance the address in your contract. Can you post your coin.balanceOf function here?

Comment: Yes, 'coin' is the contract with the same address. 
balanceOf.call(accounts[0]) in React
coin.balanceOf(eth.accounts[0]) in geth

You can see in the picture that accounts[0] is the same for both.

It really is super weird.  Feels like 2 different blockchains but both live in the same endpoint and port...